# Is there a better way to loop through an array to check for duplicates?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to check on each 'spin' if there has been a duplicate of the bonus multiplier, I've tried a few different ways to loop through the spunBonuses array but can't seem to get it to get the function to return true if there are multiple occurrences of any given array object.

Below is my current code, is there a better way to do this?

(Using TypeScipt)

```
            let spinAmount = 0;
            let spunNumbers = [];
            let spunBonuses = [];
            let safeNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
            let safeBonuses = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
            let count15 = 0, count16 = 0, count17 = 0, count18 = 0, count19 = 0, count20 = 0;
            let bonusNumber = null;

            function getSpin() {
                let numberSpun = null;
                let bonusSpun = null;
                let randomSafeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * safeNumbers.length)

                numberSpun = safeNumbers[randomSafeNumber];
                safeNumbers.splice(randomSafeNumber, 1);
                bonusSpun = safeBonuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * safeBonuses.length)];
                spunBonuses.push(bonusSpun);

                if (bonusSpun == 15) {
                    count15 += 1;
                } else if (bonusSpun == 16) {
                    count16 += 1;
                } else if (bonusSpun == 17) {
                    count17 += 1;
                } else if (bonusSpun == 18) {
                    count18 += 1;
                } else if (bonusSpun == 19) {
                    count19 += 1;
                } else if (bonusSpun == 20) {
                    count20 += 1;
                }
            }

            while (spinAmount < 4) {
                if (count15 < 2 && count16 < 2 && count17 < 2 && count18 < 2 && count19 < 2 && count20 < 2) {
                    getSpin();
                    spinAmount += 1;
                } else { spinAmount = 4; }
            }

            if (count15 == 2) {
                bonusNumber = 15;
            } else if (count16 == 2) {
                bonusNumber = 16;
            } else if (count17 == 2) {
                bonusNumber = 17;
            } else if (count18 == 2) {
                bonusNumber = 18;
            } else if (count19 == 2) {
                bonusNumber = 19;
            } else if (count20 == 2) {
                bonusNumber = 20;
            }

            console.log("Bonus achieved: " + bonusNumber);
```

Comment: use a `Set`. then look to see if its in the array.

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you elaborate on how I could check for two occurrences of the same number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map`, it is a key-value data-structure - which only holds unique keys.

Take this for an example :

```
let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,2,3];

let myMap = new Map();

for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
  if(myMap.has(list[i]))
    myMap.set(list[i],myMap.get(list[i])+1);
  else
    myMap.set(list[i],1);
}

for (let entry of myMap.entries()) {
    console.log(entry[0], entry[1]);    
}
```

What I am doing over here : 
 1. First **loop through entire array** and insert them in the map by checking if they are in the map already or not, if they are present, then I get that the current count of that element and increment it by 1, otherwise I insert that element with the count 1.
 2. At the end I am printing the key(all elements of the array),value (number of times they occur)

**So to accomplish what you want, you can now just loop through the values of map and see if any count is greater than 1, then return accordingly or you can store the corresponding key to also know which element is repeating.**

**EDIT:**
https://repl.it/repls/ExcellentOldLicense

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only thing with this, is wouldn't it keep adding 1 onto prior numbers regardless of if they've been found again? For example, if you roll a 15 and then an 18, the map will still think there has been two 15's as it re-loops through the list as a whole making it 15, 15, 18

Comment: No, how it works is if you get a 15 - it checks in the map if 15 is present or not. If present, then get the current count of 15 and add 1 to it, otherwise insert a 15 with the count 1.

So when it gets 18, it checks and because it does not find that number - it is inserted as a new key in the map with value 1.

Comment: Check my edit, to see the live working of the presented code. Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: What if you use this map within a function? As currently I'm running the check each time a duplicate is not found, which is causing the list to add one onto prior spun bonuses regardless

Comment: If you use a map within a function, and if you do the declaration there itself then every time new instance of that map would be created.

I don't know if I am getting your question correctly - so you want to reset the map once you have found the first duplicate ? right ?